# Application.CutCopyMode is not available in Excel office.js API. How can I stop paste values in cells in Excel Web Addin

Tags: excel, office-addins

I am working on a web addin using Office.js API. When I paste values in an range from external Excel file, the existing conditional formatting and other formatting get changed. I have two options; 1. Stop paste from external source and 2. Remove formats of source data and paste only values in the cells range.
Please help/suggest me how I can perform these actions.